# understanding backtracking (robot on the grid)

Tags: java, backtracking

Here is the code for a robot that moves on a grid, which is suppose to move from top left to bottom right and find unique ways to reach bottom right:

```
public static int findNumPath(int row, int col){
int total = 0;

//if grid[2][2] is reached, 1 path is found
if(row == 2 && col == 2){
    return 1;
}
grid[row][col] = true;
print();

if(col < 2 && grid[row][col+1] == false){
    System.out.println("inside 1st if" + " ,total= " + total);
    total = total + findNumPath(row, col+1);
}
if(col > 0 && grid[row][col-1] == false){
    System.out.println("inside 2nd if" + " ,total= " + total);
    total = total + findNumPath(row, col-1);
}
if(row < 2 && grid[row+1][col] == false){
    System.out.println("inside 3rd if" + " ,total= " + total);
    total = total + findNumPath(row+1, col);
}
if(row > 0 && grid[row-1][col] == false ){
    System.out.println("inside 4th if"+ " ,total= " + total);
    total = total + findNumPath(row-1, col);
}

grid[row][col] = false;
System.out.println("after making false" + " total=" + total);
return total;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
true false false 
false false false 
false false false 

inside 1st if ,total= 0
true true false 
false false false 
false false false 

inside 1st if ,total= 0
true true true 
false false false 
false false false 

inside 3rd if ,total= 0
true true true 
false false true 
false false false 

inside 2nd if ,total= 0
true true true 
false true true 
false false false 

inside 2nd if ,total= 0
true true true 
true true true 
false false false 

inside 3rd if ,total= 0
true true true 
true true true 
true false false 

inside 1st if ,total= 0
true true true 
true true true 
true true false 

inside 1st if ,total= 0
after making false total=1
after making false total=1
after making false total=1
inside 3rd if ,total= 1
true true true 
false true true 
false true false 

inside 1st if ,total= 0
inside 2nd if ,total= 1
true true true 
false true true 
true true false 

inside 4th if ,total= 0
true true true 
true true true 
true true false 

after making false total=0
after making false total=0
after making false total=1
after making false total=2
inside 3rd if ,total= 2
after making false total=3
after making false total=3
inside 3rd if ,total= 3
true true false 
false true false 
false false false 

inside 1st if ,total= 0
true true false 
false true true 
false false false 

inside 3rd if ,total= 0
inside 4th if ,total= 1
true true true 
false true true 
false false false 

after making false total=0
after making false total=1
inside 2nd if ,total= 1
true true false 
true true false 
false false false 

inside 3rd if ,total= 0
true true false 
true true false 
true false false 

inside 1st if ,total= 0
true true false 
true true false 
true true false 

inside 1st if ,total= 0
after making false total=1
after making false total=1
after making false total=1
inside 3rd if ,total= 2
true true false 
false true false 
false true false 

inside 1st if ,total= 0
inside 2nd if ,total= 1
true true false 
false true false 
true true false 

inside 4th if ,total= 0
true true false 
true true false 
true true false 

after making false total=0
after making false total=0
after making false total=1
after making false total=3
after making false total=6
inside 3rd if ,total= 6
true false false 
true false false 
false false false 

inside 1st if ,total= 0
true false false 
true true false 
false false false 

inside 1st if ,total= 0
true false false 
true true true 
false false false 

inside 3rd if ,total= 0
inside 4th if ,total= 1
true false true 
true true true 
false false false 

inside 2nd if ,total= 0
true true true 
true true true 
false false false 

after making false total=0
after making false total=0
after making false total=1
inside 3rd if ,total= 1
true false false 
true true false 
false true false 

inside 1st if ,total= 0
inside 2nd if ,total= 1
true false false 
true true false 
true true false 

after making false total=0
after making false total=1
inside 4th if ,total= 2
true true false 
true true false 
false false false 

inside 1st if ,total= 0
true true true 
true true false 
false false false 

inside 3rd if ,total= 0
true true true 
true true true 
false false false 

inside 3rd if ,total= 0
after making false total=1
after making false total=1
after making false total=1
after making false total=3
inside 3rd if ,total= 3
true false false 
true false false 
true false false 

inside 1st if ,total= 0
true false false 
true false false 
true true false 

inside 1st if ,total= 0
inside 4th if ,total= 1
true false false 
true true false 
true true false 

inside 1st if ,total= 0
true false false 
true true true 
true true false 

inside 3rd if ,total= 0
inside 4th if ,total= 1
true false true 
true true true 
true true false 

inside 2nd if ,total= 0
true true true 
true true true 
true true false 

after making false total=0
after making false total=0
after making false total=1
inside 4th if ,total= 1
true true false 
true true false 
true true false 

inside 1st if ,total= 0
true true true 
true true false 
true true false 

inside 3rd if ,total= 0
true true true 
true true true 
true true false 

inside 3rd if ,total= 0
after making false total=1
after making false total=1
after making false total=1
after making false total=2
after making false total=3
after making false total=3
after making false total=6
after making false total=12
12
```

I recently learned about backtracking, and I am trying to understand this code that how backtracking operates, however I don't understand what is happening after we find the first path, how the program knows to go back and make some of TRUEs to FALSE:

```
inside 1st if ,total= 0
after making false total=1
after making false total=1
after making false total=1
inside 3rd if ,total= 1
true true true 
false true true 
false true false
```

An explanation would be really appreciated to help me understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above code is not really backtracking, but a recursive searching algorithm. It searches your grid recursively through, moving depth-first, left, right, down, up, in this order.

It marks a field with *true* when it moves over it, and marks it with *false* when it exhausted all possibilities from that position (for the current visited fields). It marks the fields, because it does not revisit a field twice, so it searches for paths that visit each field at most once.

Note, that it does evaluate a field again for each path that leads to that field.